# Set Identification: 2011 set, bag 3, #135149

Tags: set-identification, sets

[image]

Can anyone help identify which set this bag comes from?

Answer (score 3):

This bag is from [75092-1: Naboo Starfighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75092-1/Naboo-Starfighter)

[image]

Based on

- [4655280: Plate 4X4 W/Angle](https://brickset.com/parts/4655280/plate-4x4-w-angle)
- [4260934: Left Shell 2X6W/Bow/Angle,Inv](https://brickset.com/parts/4260934/left-shell-2x6w-bow-angle-inv)